# Publising nuget package with Powershell scripts - scripts are not packaged

Tags: nuget, azure-devops, nuget-package, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am using Visual Studio Team Services to package a folder and pr documentation I have added a content folder, also tried with contentFiles folder, that contains another folder and then my powershell script. The package is created, but the content folder is not packaged.

Structure is like `/content/ReleaseScripts/MyScript.ps1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you package project file directly, you need to change that file’s Build Action to Content. (Right click the file in VS > Properties >Change Build Action to Content)

If you just create .nuspec file in a folder (no project file, such as .csproj) and pack this .nuspec file, you can refer to these steps:

1. Add **Nuget.exe** tool to source control and map to build agent (**same folder level (content folder)** that you need to package) or add it to the environment variable (path) of build agent service account.
2. Add **Command Line** task (Tool: `nugget.exe`; Arguments: `spec`; Working folder:[`same level path that you need to package, such as the folder path that contains content folder`]
3. Add **NuGet Packager** task (Path to csproj or nuspec files to pack: `**\*.nuspec`)

Comment: Previously stated it didn't work, I was wrong, worked like a charm to set Build Action to Content.